# Error passing image path to Flask application

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask application that it supposed to receive two images and output a  , but when I run the app I get these errors, the code is working perfectly without Flask

Errors:

```
[ WARN:0@11.916] global /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp (239) findDecoder imread_('/home/criuser/TÃ©lÃ©chargements/20210728_122019.jpg'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
[2022-02-15 22:17:15,439] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/criuser/PycharmProjects/FINAL_AI/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/criuser/PycharmProjects/FINAL_AI/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/criuser/PycharmProjects/FINAL_AI/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/criuser/PycharmProjects/FINAL_AI/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/home/criuser/PycharmProjects/FINAL_AI/venv/final.py", line 19, in API
    result = change_bg.change_bg_img(f_image_path=original,
  File "/home/criuser/PycharmProjects/FINAL_AI/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pixellib/tune_bg/__init__.py", line 236, in change_bg_img
    seg_image = self.segmentAsPascalvoc(f_image_path)
  File "/home/criuser/PycharmProjects/FINAL_AI/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pixellib/tune_bg/__init__.py", line 53, in segmentAsPascalvoc
    h, w, n = image.shape
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2022 22:17:15] "GET /?original=/home/criuser/TÃ©lÃ©chargements/20210728_122019.jpg&background=/home/criuser/TÃ©lÃ©chargements/Tableau_Dashboard.jpg HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Code:

> curl
> "http://127.0.0.1:5000?original=/home/criuser/Téléchargements/20210728_122019.jpg&background=/home/criuser/Téléchargements/Tableau_Dashboard.jpg"

```
@app.route('/',methods=['GET'])
def API():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        original = request.args.get('original')
        background = request.args.get('background')
        change_bg = alter_bg(model_type="pb")
        change_bg.load_pascalvoc_model("/home/criuser/Téléchargements/xception_pascalvoc.pb")
        result = change_bg.change_bg_img(f_image_path=original,
                                b_image_path=background,
                                output_image_name="/home/criuser/Téléchargements/new.jpg")
        img_base64 = base64.b64encode(result.read())
        return jsonify(img_base64.decode())
```

Comment: error shows that you get `None` instead image. First you could use `print()` to check what you get in variables.  And next you could use `if/else` to skip code when you get `None` in `original` or `background`. BTW: you don't have to check `request.method == 'GET':` because you have `methods=['GET']` . But checking `request.method == 'GET':` doesn't check if you have  `?original=... &background=...` in url.

Comment: it would be better to send JSON with field i.e. `"status": "ok"` when you send image, or `"status": "error"`when it couldn't create image.

Comment: first you could check what you have in `request.args` . Maybe problem makes native chars `é` because it shows `TÃ©lÃ©chargements` instead of `Téléchargements`

Comment: I tested code and it seems problem makes `curl` which doesn't convert `é`. If I test your URL using web browser then it gets correctly  `Téléchargements`. Maybe `curl` uses different encoding to send native chars.

Comment: running `'Ã©'.encode('latin1').decode()` I get `é` - and it can means `curl` sends URL as `latin1` but `flask` expects `utf-8`. Web browser and command `wget` don't have this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is `curl`, not `flask`.

It seems `curl` sends it as `latin1` (`iso-8859-1`) instead of `utf-8` so it converts `é` into `Ã©` - and later `flask` has problem to open `TÃ©lÃ©chargements` (instead of `Téléchargements`)

Code `'Ã©'.encode('latin1').decode()` gives `é` - so it can confirm that it uses `latin1`.

---

This works correctly in `curl`:

```
curl -GET 'http://127.0.0.1:5000' --data-urlencode 'original=/home/criuser/Téléchargements/20210728_122019.jpg' --data-urlencode 'background=/home/criuser/Téléchargements/Tableau_Dashboard.jpg'
```

---

Original url

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000?original=/home/criuser/Téléchargements/20210728_122019.jpg&background=/home/criuser/Téléchargements/Tableau_Dashboard.jpg
```

works correctly (for me) with:

- web browser (Firefox, Chrome)
- console command `wget`
- console command `http` (python module [httpie](https://github.com/httpie/httpie))
- python module `requests`
- tools to test web page (API) [postman](https://www.postman.com/), [insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/download)

but standard module `urllib.request` has problem with native chars (it encodes with `ascii`)

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation